# Can't scrape few field using css selector and selector gadget

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

So, I have a project to scrape data from class-central.com.  I used selector gadget to get the .css tags for a few fields, but when I run my program, all I get is an empty field. I am unable to identify error in my code so please help!
(PS:I am new to scrapy and this is my first project. So please make sure that your answer is understandable for someone like me)

open the following link to see the fields:https://www.classcentral.com/subject/cs

I am unable to scrape the following fields:

1. start_date: Date at which a course starts.
2. via: The website which is hosting the course(eg.Coursera).
3. Rating: The number of stars this course has been given and number of reviews.

   ```
   import scrapy
     from ..items import ClasscentralItem
     class ClassCentral(scrapy.Spider):
         name = 'spidy'
         start_urls = [
             'https://www.classcentral.com/subject/cs'
         ]
     def parse(self, response):
         items = ClasscentralItem()
         all_tr = response.css('.xlarge-up-width-9-16')
         courses = response.css('.number-of-courses .text--bold::text')
         for x in all_tr:
             sub = response.css('.medium-up-head-1::text').extract()
             course_name = x.css('.course-name .text--        bold::text').extract()
             course_devloper = x.css('.uni-name::text').extract()
             via = x.css('.hover-initiativelinks , #course-listing-tbody .text--italic::text').extract()
             duration = x.css('.icon-clock-charcoal::text').extract()
             start_date = x.css('#course-listing-tbody .medium-only-hidden::text').extract()
             rating =x.css('.review-rating::text').extract()
             items['subjectname'] = sub
             items['course_name'] = course_name
             items['course_devloper'] = course_devloper
             items['via'] = via
             items['duration'] = duration
             items['start_date'] = start_date
             items['rating'] = rating
             yield items
   ```

Comment: please, define 'I am unable'. is there any error? How do you run the scrape process?

Comment: @rok  Sir, I am just asking why is it that few fields are blank while the compiler is not showing any error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your `all_tr` is just a list of all `Course Name` columns (instead of all table rows). That's why you can't get `start_date` from `x` (it's in another column).

```
def parse(self, response):

    items = {}
    all_tr = response.css('#course-listing-tbody tr')
    courses = response.css('.number-of-courses .text--bold::text')
    for x in all_tr:
        sub = response.css('.medium-up-head-1::text').extract()
        course_name = x.css('.course-name .text--bold::text').get()
        course_devloper = x.css('.uni-name::text').extract()
        via = x.css('.text--italic::text').get()
        duration = x.css('.icon-clock-charcoal::text').extract()
        start_date = x.css('.medium-only-hidden::text').get()
        rating =x.css('td:nth-child(4)').attrib['data-timestamp']
        items['subjectname'] = sub
        items['course_name'] = course_name
        items['course_devloper'] = course_devloper
        items['via'] = via
        items['duration'] = duration
        items['start_date'] = start_date
        items['rating'] = rating
        yield items
```

**UPDATE** For `rating` I grab `data-timestamp` attribute of the 4th column (Rating)

If you look at the page source you'll find that some rows don't have course details (ads rows). That's why you get an error after 5 results. To get all course you need to modify `all_tr` selector:

```
all_tr = response.css('#course-listing-tbody tr[itemscope]')
```

Comment: Hi, Can you explain what have you done with the tag 'rating' . Also now the spider is only giving me an output for 5 courses, while the webpage has more than 10 courses. Can you you throw light on that as well?

Comment: Hi Sir, Thank you for your help. Just 1 last question,  what does [itemscope] do ?  Is it in the source code of the page ?

Comment: Also, why are you using .get() at some places while you are using .extract() at other places while not using either for rating?

Comment: `itemscope` is a HTML attribute of the `tr` tag. I used it to filter out data rows.

Comment: Also I used `.get()` only for the variables you asked. `.get()` is the same as `.extract_first()`. I didn't touch your `.extract()` but I'm sure that you need to use `.get()` or `.extract_first()` for these values.

Comment: Using .extract_first() makes sense when we are extracting a list, but for fields start_date why is .get() necessary ?

Comment: `extract()` **always** returns you a list but I (and you) need a **single** value instead that's why I used `get()` (or `extract_first()`)